# Recargar una página y mostrar un mensaje "alertify"

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo un reporte de datos donde tengo la opción de editar y eliminar registros.

Cuando clickeo en una opción para editar se abre una ventana emergente (Modal Bootstrap), donde edito y guardo los datos, y luego de editar los campos y dar click en el botón ACTUALIZAR del MODAL quiero que se recargue la página donde estoy y que luego de eso me aparezca un mensaje SUCCESS *Alertify*.

He intentado hacerlo pero lo que llegué hacer es poder recargar la página y los efectos realizados se ejecutan correctamente, pero no puedo hacer que luego de que se recargue la página y todo eso, aparezca este mensaje de SUCCESS.

Aquí dejo el codigo:

**funciones_actividad.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#actualizadatos').click(function() {
  actualizaDatos();
 });

});

function agregaForm(datos){
 d = datos.split('||');

 $('#id').val(d[0]);
 $('#evidencia').val(d[1]);
 $('#hito_actividad').val(d[2]);
}

function actualizaDatos(){

 var datos = $('#form_editar_actividad').serialize();

 $.ajax({
  url: "php/editar_datos.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: datos,
  dataType: 'json',

  success:function(datos){
   if (datos.exito==true) {
            
    window.location.reload(true);

                   //En esta parte coloco el codigo para que me aparezca el mensaje luego de recargar pero no ocurre nada.
                  //alertify.success("Se Actualizaron los Datos con Éxito");
         
         
   }
   else{
    if (datos.evidencia) {
     alertify.error(datos.evidencia);
    }
    if (datos.hito_actividad) {
     alertify.error(datos.hito_actividad);
    }
    if (datos.fecha_hito) {
     alertify.error(datos.fecha_hito);
    }
    if (datos.estado_hito) {
     alertify.error(datos.estado_hito);
    }
    if (datos.avance) {
     alertify.error(datos.avance);
    }
   }
  }
 }) 
}
function preguntar(id){
 alertify.confirm('Eliminar Datos', '¿Está seguro de eliminar este registro?', function(){ eliminarDatos(id) }
                ,  function(){ alertify.error('Cancelado')});
}
```

Comment: Lo que propones es un poco raro.
¿No seria mejor mostrar primero el SUCCESS y luego recargar?.
De otra forma tendrias que hacer un checkeo al iniciar la página, algo un tanto raro. Otra forma sería editar el html con los datos actualizados.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que sucede (o al menos lo que entiendo con el código) es que el mensaje de éxito está programado después de la recarga, pero al refrescarse la página está vuelve a iniciar el JS desde 0, o sea que nunca llegará a ejecutarse.

Lo que se me ocurre si quieres mostrar el mensaje después es guardar una variable ya sea en un parámetro de la URL, Cookies o LocalStorage

```
// En la URL
window.location.search = 'actualizado';

// En las Cookies
document.cookie = 'actualizado=true';

// En LocalStorage
window.localStorage.setItem('actualizado', true);


// Después refrescamos la pagina
window.location.reload(true);
```

Y al cargar la pagina comprobar que la variable esta definida

```
// En la URL
window.location.search.includes('actualizado');

// En las cookies
document.cookie.includes('actualizado=true');

// En LocalStorage
window.localStorage.getItem('actualizado') == true;
```

**Ejemplo con LocalStorage:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.localStorage.getItem('actualizado') == true) {
    alertify.success("Se Actualizaron los Datos con Éxito");

    // Opcionalmente puedes borrar o establecer la variable en "false"
  }
});


function actualizaDatos() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "php/editar_datos.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: datos,
    dataType: 'json',

    success:function(datos) {
      if (datos.exito==true) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('actualizado', true);
        window.location.reload(true);
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Aportar un ejemplo en código de lo que dices, mejoriaría en mucho la respuesta. Considera añadir un ejemplo funcional.

Comment: Listo, espero quede mas claro ahora